# Using sqlmap to find password hashes

Tags: passwords, hash, sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

I'm learning SQL-injection (and SQL in the first place) by playing a CTF. I'm using `sqlmap` and have for my target IP so far found:

Uses: `MySQL, PHP`

2 databases:

```
information_schema
users
```

1 table in users database:

```
user
```

if I dump the `user` table in the `users` database I get:

```
+------------------------------+----------+
| name                         | username |
+------------------------------+----------+
| YouWillNeverCrakThisPassword | nochance |
| Jack Bob                     | jack     |
| Bill Sims                    | bill     |
| Bob Browne                   | Bob      |
+------------------------------+----------+
```

But there isn't any password hashes for me to try and crack. In the tutorial I've been following this is where the hashes were.

Any idea where the password hashes might be? Do they have to be somewhere? I don't know much about the schema, but I didn't really see anything in there.

Comment: Which CTF are you doing?

Comment: I've sometimes experienced that some CTF solutions are simpler than you might think. Are you sure the flag isn't simply "YouWillNeverCrakThisPassword"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* `user` **table** (Note: singular) you are looking for is in the `mysql` db not the `users` db (Note: plural). The `users` *database* you are referring to is probably something you (or DVWA, *or whatever you're practicing with* created). If you want the MYSQL users (and hashes), you'll need to get to the database engine's configuration tables, specifically: `user`.

**REFERENCE**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html

Comment: Hmm so if `--dbs` didn't show a database named `mysql` does that mean I need to find a different website address to start from?

Comment: It could be a lot of things. For one, the context (aka user) the webserver is using to query mysql may not have permission to view that DB. Can you login to mysql as root and see if the table exists?

Comment: I don't have any access all I was given to start with was an IP address of the target. It's a page with a PHP username input and running dirbuster on the IP with a large list hasn't shown me anything.

Comment: Use sqlmap to find out what user you're connecting to MySQL as.

Comment: after I do that can I change user permissions or switch user?

Comment: --user --privileges and there's only 1 user and its only privilege is 'USAGE'